# template function with no object arguments specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'd like to specialize a template function to take non-pointer types and if in case it gets a pointer I'd like to call it without the *.

I'm wondering if there's a way without using std::remove_pointer.

for example I'd like to do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void setName() {
    name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
}

template<typename T>
void setName<T*>() {
    setName<T>();
}
```

`name` is defined as a private data member.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @CrazyEddie yes and I'm getting "'template<class T> void Type::setName()' cannot be overloaded"

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is correct but partial function template specialization is not allowed in C++. Fortuately partial class template specialization is allowed so you can use static method workaround (see specialization of `setName_impl` below) and if needed function template wrapper (see `setName()` below):

```
template<typename T>
struct setName_impl{ 
    static void exec() { }
};

template<typename T>
struct setName_impl<T*>{ 
    static void exec() {
        setName<T>::exec();
    }
};

template<typename T>
void setName() { 
    setName_impl<T>::exec(); 
}
```

Comment: but I want setName to be a function not a struct

Comment: @Loay It is struct containing a static method. See the end of my answer that I just added.

Comment: Just make a function that calls this struct's static method, which will likely be the easiest way to to this.  `template <class T> void setName() { name = setNameImpl<T>::exec(); }`

Comment: I edited the answer and added desired wrapper function template.